# Move files with batch and browse sub folders

Tags: batch-file

I created a batch file that allow to move a file from a folder to another. 
My issue is that my bat file should also browse source subfolders in order to find files that have a specific pattern.

Actually :

```
@ECHO ON
SET SourceDir=C:\Users\me\Documents\source
SET CopyDir=C:\Users\me\Documents\repository
SET FilePatterName=*pattern*.pdf

FOR %%A IN ("%SourceDir%\%FilePatterName%") DO (
    ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%%~A" "%CopyDir%\"
    DEL /Q /F "%%~A"
)
GOTO EOF
```

For example : in my source folder, if i have sub1, sub2, sub3 folders and a sub1-1 folder in sub1, i would like to check each folders, check the files and move them without creating any folder in the repository

Comment: `for /R "%SourceDir%"  %%A in ("%FilePatterName%") do`

Comment: it's very ugly but it works ! thanks a lot.

Comment: Well not ugly. That is how it works withou having to add `dir` or `where` commands. I will post an answer to make it look prettier though.

Comment: i'm not used to do bash stuffs :) it's perfectly do the job.

Comment: A [tag:batch-file] isn't the Bourne Again SHell, [tag:bash]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, use `for /r` which will recurse through the directories:

```
for /R "%SourceDir%" %%A in ("%FilePatterName%") do...
```

if it feels too *ugly* then first pushd to the directory, then recursively search from there:

```
@Echo off
Set "SourceDir=C:\Users\me\Documents\source"
Set "CopyDir=C:\Users\me\Documents\repository"
Set FilePatterName=*pattern*.pdf
Pushd "%SourceDir%"

For /R %%a in ("%FilePatterName%") do (
    Echo F | Xcopy /Y /F "%%~a" "%CopyDir%\"
    Del /Q /F "%%~a"
)
Popd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, using the same structure but [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) instead of [xcopy](/questions/tagged/xcopy) and [del](/questions/tagged/del):

```bat
@Set "SourceDir=%UserProfile%\Documents\source"
@Set "CopyDir=%UserProfile%\Documents\repository"
@Set "FilePatterName=*pattern*.pdf"
@If Exist "%SourceDir%\" For /R "%SourceDir%" %%# In ("%FilePatterName%")Do @"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "%%~dp#." "%CopyDir%" "%%~nx#" /Mov>NUL 2>&1
```

If you really needed to see the filenames, I suppose you could include additional `RoboCopy` options like `/FP`, `/NDL`, `/NS`, `/NC`, `/NJH` and `/NJS`.